# Get access_token when using Identity Scaffolding Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Identity Scaffolding Asp.net Core for my project Web API, when call PasswordSignInAsync and success, how to get access_token (i added Identity Scaffold Item and have this method) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvgWR.png). I need access token to response my api.

Please help me :(((